# How to send data from a microcontroller to a database without WiFi?

Tags: pcb, sensor, wifi

I am currently working on a project utilizing a microcontroller along with a couple of sensors on a PCB that will be collecting data in backyards/outside. I haven't chosen my supplies yet, and I am still researching, but before ordering parts, I want to know if the project is feasible.

I wanted to make a compact device ("module") that would collect data like temperature, light, etc. from the environment and somehow send that data to a database so that the data could be run through a ML model and make some predictions. I'd have a bunch of these devices scattered around a yard or area (usually the yards don't have WiFi but are close to a WiFi source).

The problem I am having is figuring out how I will send the data after collecting it if there is no WiFi in the area of collection. I have heard of "ESP Now" which can communicate data between devices using MAC addresses, but I don't want to get such an expensive device for each module as the only thing I want to do is collect and send data. As stated before, I would like to keep it simple by using a small microcontroller (a PIC10F200, for example) as the use case for me is not that large.

What can I do to send data to a database from these devices and what microcontrollers should I look into getting?

PS:
One solution I may have is to have a receiver near the house and somehow send the data from the sensors to the receiver and then use the receiver to send the data to the database since the receiver would be close to a house and thus would have WiFi access, but I am not sure how I would implement this and if it would even work. Any ideas?

Comment: This question might be too opinion-based to be a good fit for this site. Nonetheless you might have some luck if you look for LoRa devices. I think Adafruit and Sparkfun both sell low-cost parts and breakout boards.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will look into using a LoRa device to send the data

Comment: if you want to operate on the scale of a PIC10 that rules out pretty much everything except UHF OOK (433 or whatever) and IRDA  anything better than that and you'll be installing a better MCU to run the communication.

Comment: ok, so what microcontrollers would you recommend I use instead. (Sorry im new and don't know the differences between each one)

Comment: look at how wireless sensors for personal weather stations work

Comment: the ones you're decided that you don't want eg: ESP 8266, ESP32,  and several different bluetooth modules.  (they're about $2 each as a module and cheaper as ICs - but you need a high precision PCB and reflow soldering to use the ICs)   the developemnet kit versions are about $20 more but you only need one dev kit.  LCSC prices.

Comment: Go to Digikey, Mouser, or whoever your favorite **real** online electronic parts distributor is (*not* pAllyExpress, fleeBay, etc) and look through their lists of RF modules.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the range you might be ok with 433MHz modules as used in garage door remotes, weather stations etc.  Otherwise you could use a BLE module which provides wireless connectivity and gives you a reasonable-power microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an off the shelf wireless module, and a matching receiver connected to a PC.

I had at one point looked at some made by Raytac.  They had the following features.

- cost only a few dollars
- Rnage was over 500 feet (depending on module).
- Had options for integrated antenna or UFL external antenna.
- With some modules you could load your own code into the MCU, and with others you could just use it like a wireless serial port.
- Used Bluetooth protocol.
- There were USB dongles that had a matching receiver that looked like a COM port on your PC.

https://www.raytac.com/product/

I have also used similar modules using IEEE 802.15.4 wireless protocol that were made by Microchip corporation.

If you look on the major distributor websites, you can find quite a few modules made by various manufacturers that would meet your requirements.

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rf-transceiver-modules-and-modems/872